# How to update computed column in SQL table

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a table with computed column like below (see `IsFlag` column)

```
CREATE TABLE [TableName]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsFlag1] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [IsFlag2] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [IsFlag3] [BIT] NOT NULL,
    [IsFlag] AS (CASE WHEN [IsFlag1] = (1) OR [IsFlag2] = (1) OR [IsFlag3] = (1) THEN (1) ELSE (0) END)
)
```

The computed column is being referred to by a few indexes and views.

Now, I need to add another flag `[IsFlag4] [BIT] NOT NULL` to the table and update the computed column to

```
[IsFlag] AS (CASE WHEN [IsFlag1] = (1) OR [IsFlag2] = (1) OR 
                       [IsFlag3] = (1) OR [IsFlag4] = (1) 
                  THEN (1) ELSE (0) END)
```

The table contains a huge amount of data and drop and create of all indexes, views is a concern,

What are my options for getting this change implemented with minimal downtime?

Thanks,

Comment: [quel] [sql] [?]

Comment: Drop the index, add the column, recreate the the index -- it has to be rebuilt anyway.  All-at-once is the best approach.

Comment: Also, `IsFlag` can be simplified to `[IsFlag] AS IsFlag1 | IsFlag2 | IsFlag3`.

Comment: @HABO - Computed columns aren't stored as their original text. If you create a table with `create table T (
 ID int not null,
 Foo as CASE WHEN ID=5 THEN 1 ELSE 19 END
)` and then ask management studio to generate the create script for it, you get back `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T](
 [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Foo]  AS (case when [ID]=(5) then (1) else (19) end)
) ON [PRIMARY]`

Comment: I'd be starting to wonder if this would not be better as `ID int, FlagType int, FlagValue bit` and `IsFlag` computed as an aggregate over this table instead. How many more `IsFlagX` columns are you going to add before thinking that this design just doesn't scale out properly. E.g. it would then be `select ID,MAX(FlagValue) as IsFlag from table group by ID` with additional filtering as required.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Each row can have multiple Flags set. (Like Multiple Choice options) so converting the flag to `FlagType`, `FlagValue` will not work. Also, it's a legacy design so we are not sure if any change to the design will result in changes to how many places in the entire code base

Comment: `FlagType` would be `1`, `2`, `3` etc. `FlagValue` would be the existing bits. You'd switch to modelling multiple flags using multiple *rows*, not be having to alter the schema every time a new flag type is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a computed column, it doesn't take space (unless specified as [PERSISTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql))

So drop and add it again with a new calculation, after adding "IsFlag4".

Example using a temporary table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TableName; 
CREATE TABLE #TableName
(
    [ID] [INT] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsFlag1] [BIT] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [IsFlag2] [BIT] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [IsFlag3] [BIT] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    [IsFlag] AS (CASE WHEN [IsFlag1] = 1 OR [IsFlag2] = 1 OR [IsFlag3] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_TableName_IsFlag ON #TableName ([IsFlag]);  

insert into #TableName (IsFlag1, IsFlag2, IsFlag3) values (0,0,0),(0,0,1);

-- Add [IsFlag4]
ALTER TABLE #TableName ADD [IsFlag4] [BIT] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;

-- Drop and Add [IsFlag]
-- Drop index first, and add it again after
BEGIN
  DROP INDEX idx_TableName_IsFlag ON #TableName;
  ALTER TABLE #TableName DROP COLUMN [IsFlag];
  ALTER TABLE #TableName ADD [IsFlag] AS ([IsFlag1] | [IsFlag2] | [IsFlag3] | [IsFlag4]);
  CREATE INDEX idx_TableName_IsFlag ON #TableName ([IsFlag]);
END;

insert into #TableName (IsFlag1, IsFlag2, IsFlag3, IsFlag4) values (0,0,0,1);

select * from #TableName;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID  IsFlag1 IsFlag2 IsFlag3 IsFlag4 IsFlag
1   0       0       0       0       0
2   0       0       1       0       1
3   0       0       0       1       1
```

Comment: @LukStorms- Thanks for the elaborate steps. I was working on the same lines. However, the design has a different schema for every client and each schema has millions of records for the table. So doing a Drop and recreate for each schema & table will have an impact on DB availability, I was looking for some option that can minimize the DB downtime.

Comment: You should then try this on a copy of such table first. And time each statement. Adding that extra column should take much more time than re-adding that computed column.